# Issue with cookies / expiring session

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have users who write articles and when they leave there computer for a while and come back then submit a post the author / user_id is recorded as a NULL value.  I'm assuming the session is expiring.  I have:

```
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $ext = time() + 31560000;
    setcookie('name', $_SESSION['user_id'], $ext);
}
```

On the top of the index page where a user is redirected upon login.

Also, this is what happens when they actually log in:

```
$user_id = get_user_id($some_variable); // get's the user_id
$username = get_username($some_variable); // get's username

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'http://site.com/<?php echo $username; ?>';
</script>
<?php
exit();
```

Is this properly configured, and why would the user's sessions be expiring?  They're not exiting the browser, it's just inactivity.  What would be causing this?

Comment: Check what your `php.ini` setting [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) is set to.  Default is 1440 seconds or 24 minutes.  After that amount of time, there is the possibility that session data that old will be cleaned up.

Comment: Would session.gc_maxlifetime = 1000000 (random number) be the correct way to write it in the php.ini?

Comment: Yes that would do it globally.  You can also use [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) from your script, but if you do, then you have to make sure that ALL of your scripts that interact with sessions use the same values.  Make sure its large enough for your needs, but not so big you will end up with a ton of old session data on the server.

Comment: So, would it still expire after 24 min. of inactivity, but have a max of 86400 (if I supply that value)?  Or, will not expire for 86400 even with inactivity?  Inactivity is obviously the issue here.

Comment: As long as they don't close the browser, it effectively sets the maximum inactivity time before possible cleanup to 86400.  Cleanup can happen some time after that based on `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`.  You can also modify the session cookie to live after closing the browser as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you try to achieve with

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $ext = time() + 31560000;
    setcookie('name', $_SESSION['user_id'], $ext);
    }
```

But that do not increase the php session lifetime, but only create a cookie called name that have the $_SESSIOn['user_id'] as value and expire 31560000 seconds after creation.

If you want to change your session lifetime see [session.configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: I'm looking at it.  What specific function would I want to use and how would I write it?  I would want to set it for 86400 sec. just to put a number out there.

Comment: You can use the ini_set function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php or directly modify you php.ini. ex `init_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',86400);`